# How to sum the values ​of a column using the status of another column as a condition using datatable or java script

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

How to sum the values ​​of a column using the status of another column as a condition using datatable or java script

Hello I appreciate your kind attention. I am very new in this world and I have a dilemma. I am working with a table using the DATATABLE api, it has 12 columns of which there is a mount call and another transaction result call. My problem is that I need add the values ​​of the mount column if in the transaction result column it has an approved status. I managed to do the sum of said column using a code that I found right here, but it adds the column in its entirety and it does not work in the condition of the transaction result column. The result is thrown in the footer of the table. Now if, for example, I take the number from the User id column and look for it, they are filtered by the user id and the sum is updated automatically, but it still does not consider whether the status is approved or declined.

I really appreciate your kind attention and sorry for being still ignorant on the subject because js is not my strong suit yet.

I leave 2 images of the table indicating the function. and the code snippet you use.

Link here-->  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wrUYRczKvRU_CqDlAWrZZkCUaZwgggqB/view?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register('sum()', function() {
            return this.flatten().reduce(function(a, b) {
                if (typeof a === 'string') {
                  a = a.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '') * 1;
                }

                if (typeof b === 'string') {
                    b = b.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '') * 1;
                }

                return a + b;
            }, 0);
        });

        var table = $('#t_filtrada').DataTable({    
            "paging": false,   
            "ordering": false, 
            drawCallback: function() {
                var api = this.api();
                var numFormat = $.fn.dataTable.render.number('\,', '.', 2, '$').display; 

                $(api.column(2).footer()).html(
                    numFormat(api.column(2, {
                        page: 'current'
                    }).data().sum())
                );

                var total = api.column(2, {
                    "filter": "applied"
                }).data().sum();
                $('#monto').html(total);
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is just a fragment of code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's function you could run after the table has been populated and you're ready to sum() it up. It's jQuery and not a DataTable method, but it should work

```
const sum = () => {
  let sum = 0;
  $('#t_filtrada tr').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('td').eq(3).text().trim().toLowerCase() === 'approved';
  }).each(function() {
    sum += +$(this).find('td').eq(2).text().trim();
  })
  return sum
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the support, now I will study this code to apply it, I hope it works for me.

Greetings friend

Comment: I have a question.
of the code snippet that I included in this post.
Where should i insert it?

my apologies

Comment: This code snippet can be included anywhere on the page since it doesn't get executed until a button in clicked. However, if it was going to get executed automatically, just make sure it's written to the page (or in an included .js file) before it gets called.

Comment: I have not managed to make it work,
but, I suppose it is from my low knowledge in js, a screenshot of the code snippet.
since the ideal is that it is executed automatically in the table.
again, excuse my ignorance, thank you very much for the support.